# Trigger to drop a database on a particular date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to know is it possible to write a SQL trigger to drop a database automatically on a particular date.

please help me by your suggestions .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't, probably, use a trigger for this. Instead you'll use an event. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html

You can set this up using MySQL code like this.

```
DELIMITER $$

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON$$     -- required for event to execute but not create    

CREATE EVENT `Event1`
ON SCHEDULE AT '2015-04-01 00:00:00'
COMMENT 'drop my table on april fools day'
DO
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE jokes;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm sure you know what you're doing. But, doing this kind of destructive operation on a schedule seems a little risky to me.